# Why the UIWebView' address is nil?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I ask yours pardon for my English, thanks
I have two class: (COPlayerManager.h,COPlayerManager.h)  and (COGenericPlayerController.h, COGenericPlayerController.h, COGenericPlayerController.xib)

The goal is to show an image by UIWebView. So into the COGenericPlayerController's view I insert an object UIWebView from the library.

My COGenericPlayerController.h is:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AxObject.h"
#import "AxFinderAppDelegate.h"
@interface COGenericPlayerController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIToolbar* wToolbar;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView* wBrowser;
-(void) open:(NSString*) path :(NSString*) titleObj;
@end
```

and I have done all link to File's Owner.
The problem is when I alloc and init COGenericPlayerController that it lose the reference of its object (uiwebview)

```
@implementation COPlayerManager

// open a file at the input path.
-(void) open:(NSString*) path :(NSString*) titleObj :(int) tabBarIndex
    {
    .....
    .....
    else if([ext isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"png"] || [ext  isEqualToString:@"jpeg"])
    {
        **COGenericPlayerController *gPlayer = [[COGenericPlayerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"COGenericPlayerController" bundle:nil];**
    ......
    ......
```

While gPlayer is allocating and inizializing it has an address and also its object (UIWebView)
After that gPlayer is allocated and inizialized the gplayer's address exist but the UIWebView's address is nil. I think this is the issue that not allow me to display the image in the simulator Iphone's screen and I don't understand where is the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
COGenericPlayerController *gPlayer = [[COGenericPlayerController alloc] initWithNibName:@"COGenericPlayerController" bundle:nil];
```

allocates and initializes your view controller, but it won't actually allocate or instantiate your UIWebView outlet until you push that view controller into view (via a navigation controller or a segue or whatever).

Once COGenericPlayerController's "`viewDidLoad`" is called, **THAT** is when your web view exists.

Comment: Now it works right. I understand and I have inserted all the code relative at UIWebView into ViewDidLoad. Thank you very much